# How can I verify that a SQLite db3 file is valid/consistent

Tags: linux, database, sql, sqlite

I have some sqlite version3 db3 files I copied off a live running production system (I know bad sysadmin bad sysadmin) for various reasons. Is there some sqlite command I can run that will verify that all the data can be read out of these files (I don't mind if it takes a while).

I was considering hacking up some perl which dumps out all data and then re-imports it into new files. I think sqlite will throw an exception if it encounters corrupt data. Is there a better way?

I'm CentOS 5.3 and sqlite-3.3.6-2

Comment: "bad sysadmin bad sysadmin"? What's that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think you want to try:

```
pragma integrity_check;
```

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check):

> This pragma does an integrity check of the entire database. The
>   integrity_check pragma looks for out-of-order records, missing pages,
>   malformed records, missing index entries, and UNIQUE and NOT NULL
>   constraint errors. If the integrity_check pragma finds problems,
>   strings are returned (as multiple rows with a single column per row)
>   which describe the problems. [...]
>
> See also the [PRAGMA quick_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_quick_check) command which does most of the
>   checking of PRAGMA integrity_check but runs much faster.

Comment: See also http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q21

Comment: Doing this for a gnucash database 13M in size.  It returned Ok almost instantly.  Seemed too quick to actually check anything, but maybe that database is small potatoes.  Gnucash is crashing, which is why I am checking.